# Map arrays to objects with no common fields

Tags: json, bash, merge, jq

How might one use `jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe` to join a filtered set of arrays from STDIN to a set of objects which contains no common fields, assuming that all elements will be in predictable order?

Standard Input (pre-slurpfile; generated by multiple GETs):

```
{"ref":"objA","arr":["alpha"]}
{"ref":"objB","arr":["bravo"]}
```

Existing File:

```
[{"name":"foo"},{"name":"bar"}]
```

Desired Output:

```
[{"name":"foo","arr":["alpha"]},{"name":"bar","arr":["bravo"]}]
```

Current Bash:

```
$ multiGET | jq --slurpfile stdin /dev/stdin '.[].arr = $stdin[].arr' file
[
  {
    "name": "foo",
    "arr": [
      "alpha"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "bar",
    "arr": [
      "alpha"
    ]
  }
]
[
  {
    "name": "foo",
    "arr": [
      "bravo"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "bar",
    "arr": [
      "bravo"
    ]
  }
]
```

Sidenote: I wasn't sure when to use pretty/compact JSON in this question; please comment with your opinion on best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get jq to read `file` before stdin, so that the first entity in `file` will be `.` and you can get everything else using `inputs`.

```
$ multiGET | jq -c '. as $objects
| [ foreach (inputs | {arr}) as $x (-1; .+1;
    . as $i | $objects[$i] + $x
) ]' file -
[{"name":"foo","arr":["alpha"]},{"name":"bar","arr":["bravo"]}]
```

Comment: I like this solution because it doesn't require deleting the irrelevant key(s).

Comment: I'm selecting your answer because of this comment; please edit to make it the first thing read by anyone who stumbles on this question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

1. "Slurping" (whether using `-s` or `--slurpfile`) is sometimes necessary but rarely desirable, because of the memory requirements.  So here's a solution that takes advantage of the fact that your multiGET produces a stream:

```
multiGET | jq -n --argjson objects '[{"name":"foo"},{"name":"bar"}]' '
  $objects
  | [foreach inputs as $in (-1; .+1; 
      . as $ix
      | $objects[$ix] + ($in | del(.ref)))]
'
```

2. Here's a functional approach that might be appropriate if your stream was in fact already packaged as an array:

```
multiGET | jq -s --argjson objects '[{"name":"foo"},{"name":"bar"}]' '
  [$objects, map(del(.ref))]
  | transpose
  | map(add)
'
```

3. If the `$objects` array is in a file or too big for the command line, I'd suggest using `--argfile`, even though it is technically deprecated.
4. If the $objects array is in a file, and if you want to avoid `--argfile`, you could still avoid slurping, e.g. by using the fact that unless `-n` is used, jq will automatically read one JSON entity from `stdin`:

```
(echo '[{"name":"foo"},{"name":"bar"}]';
 multiGET) | jq '
   . as $objects
   | [foreach inputs as $in (-1; .+1;
        . as $ix | $objects[$ix] + $in | del(.ref))] 
'
```

Comment: Looks like the last one is similar to mine but much better. I think you should show it also can be used like `multiGET | jq ... file -` and I can delete my answer

Comment: I'd suggest keeping yours. It shows how `reduce` can also be used, with its pluses and minuses.

Comment: Okay then. Looks like `+=` is also implemented using reduce/foreach, and working on a large object in reduce really slows down the program

Comment: I selected oguz's modified answer because it was the simplest to implement in a complex shell script, but I want to thank you for taking the time to write and explain multiple approaches. Your answer was a great exercise which improved my understanding of the language as a whole.